# Aliens double the population

Tags: population

As a prank, aliens come to earth and double our population. This new people are integrated, with false records, and the aliens messed with our heads so we can't reliably tell old people from new people. No one can tell if they themselves are old or new, since the new people have false memories. The aliens weren't perfect though, and with detailed investigations we can tell people apart if we wanted to, but we probably couldn't do it on a massive scale. Relative population densities and all demographics are the same.

What are the short and long term consequences?

Comment: You may be submitting too many questions, and not taking enough time on them.  This one is not consistent.  How can you double the population of the Earth without increasing the population density?

Comment: @CortAmmon Sorry, I'll slow down. Also, I clarified.

Comment: Relative population densities?

Comment: @Jimmy360 Relative to each other.

Comment: Ah... okay I see

Comment: Will the false memories extend to current address? If so, how to accommodate the doubled housing density?

Comment: If they place false memories, how would we know they haven't already done so?

Comment: @GrandmasterB No random population spike

Comment: Your aliens really have an interesting sense of humour, i'll grant you that.

Answer (score 2):

**Starvation and dehydration everywhere:**

> "The 3.5 billion acres would produce approximately 2 billion tons of
>   grains annually, he explained. That's enough to feed 10 billion
>   vegetarians, but would only feed 2.5 billion U.S. omnivores, because
>   so much vegetation is dedicated to livestock and poultry in the United
>   States." ([source](http://www.livescience.com/16493-people-planet-earth-support.html))

That means that the earth's carrying capacity is 10 billion. Your aliens have put us at 14 billion. Also, with limited freshwater resources, many would be thristy.

Comment: Followed by massive riots and wars to obtain more food and land for these people.

Answer (score 1):

As "new" people isn't natural, it's a rich theme for a discrimination. As soon, as "old" people discover newcomers, there will began a hunt for slavery.
The main reason, as Jimmy360 noted, is lack of resources, so from one community to another newcomers will be pressed to hard labor "to work out resources they stole from us". New profession, newcomer headhunter, will get popular.
And then we come to the "Bladerunner".

Comment: Don't forget the old comer hunters. There is as many of them as us.

Comment: Let the Hunter Game begin!

Comment: Nope, they don't know if they are newcomers or oldcomers. And, as newcomers are discovered by one at a time by a hunter, they are common to be a minority. But, your point is interesting, though.